# Attempting to pass an object to a class causes an unset variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to set up a class for the simplification of MySQLi queries using the mysqli class. However, when I set up my class to accept an instance of mysqli, I receive this error:

> Undefined variable: dbobj in C:\wamp\www\inc\classes\ezsql.class.php on line 93

I've never really done dependency injection before, plus my coding skills aren't with me today, so syntax mistakes might be plentiful.

Here's the class I've created:

```
<?php

/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EZSQL

A PHP class that utilizes the PDO MySQLi DB class to make database querying easier and quicker.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

class EZSQL {
    public $dbobj;

    public function __construct( mysqli $dbobject ) {
        echo "var_dunp before making this->dbobj\n";
        var_dump( $dbobj );
        if ( is_object( $dbobject ) ) {
            $this->dbobj = $dbobject;
        } else {
            // Just in case...
            die( "EZSQL Error #0: EZSQL must be initialized with a PDO MySQLi DB instance." );
        }
        echo "var_dunp after making this->dbobj\n";
        var_dump( $this->dbobj );
    }

    public function select( $exp, $table, $where ) {
        // Make $where optional
        if ( isset( $where ) ) {
            $queryString = "SELECT {$exp} FROM {$table} WHERE {$where}";
        } else {
            $queryString = "SELECT {$exp} FROM {$table}";
        }

        if ( $returnObj = $this->dbobj->query( $queryString ) ) {
            $return = $returnObj->fetch_assoc();
            return $return;
        } else {
            // Some error handling
            die( "[EZSQL]: SQL SELECT query error #{$this->dbobj->errno}: {$this->dbobj->error}" );
        }
    }

    public function insert( $tab, $cols, $values ) {
        // Create the general query string format
        $queryString = "INSERT INTO {$tab} (";
        $colsCt = count( $cols );
        foreach ( $cols as $key=>$col ) {
            if ( $key != ( $colsCt - 1 ) ) {
                $queryString .= "{$col}, ";
            } else {
                $queryString .= "{$col})";
            }
        }

        // More general formatting
        $queryString .= " VALUES (";
        $valCt = count( $values );
        foreach( $values as $key=>$value ) {
            if ( $key != ( $valCt - 1 ) ) {
                $queryString .= "{$value}, ";
            } else {
                $queryString .= "{$value})";
            }
        }

        if ( $query = $this->dbobj->prepare( $queryString ) ) {
            $query->execute();
        } else {
            die( "[EZSQL]: SQL INSERT query prepare error #{$this->dbobj->errno}: {$this->dbobj->error}" );
        }
    }

    public function createTable( $name, $ino, $colData ) {
        // Create the general query string format
        $queryString = "CREATE TABLE";
        if ( $ino ) {
            $queryString .= " IF NOT EXISTS";
        }
        $queryString .= " {$name}";

        $colCt = count( $colData );

        $queryString .= " (";

        $iter = 1;

        foreach ( $colData as $name=>$type ) {
            $iter++;
            if ( $iter != ( $colCt ) ) {
                $queryString .= " {$name} {$type},";
            } else {
                $queryString .= " {$name} {$type});";
            }
        }

        if ( !$this->dbobj->query( $queryString ) ) {
            die( "[EZSQL]: SQL CREATE TABLE query error #{$this->dbobj->errno}: {$this->dbobj->error}" );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Line 93 is contained inside the function createTable, specifically this if statement:

```
if ( !$this->dbobj->query( $queryString ) ) {
     die( "[EZSQL]: SQL CREATE TABLE query error #{$this->dbobj->errno}: {$this->dbobj->error}" );
}
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated, as I can't quite tell what is wrong.

Again, keep in mind I am new to dependency injection. Syntax errors in PHP are not a rarity for me.

Thanks.

**Edit 1:** Here's the connection I'm using in my index.php page:

```
<?php
require( "inc/classes/ezsql.class.php" );
// require( "inc/config.php" );
// require( "inc/proc/db.php" );

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "testdb";
$port = "3306";

$db = new mysqli( $host, $user, $pass, $db, $port );

echo "var_dunp before creating instance of EZSQL\n";
var_dump( $db );

if ( !$db ) {
    die( "error" );
}

$ezsql = new EZSQL( $db );

$cols = array(
    "int" => "int",
    "text" => "varchar(255)"
    );

$ezsql->createTable( "test1", TRUE, $cols );
?>
```

**Edit 2:** Added var_dump()s to certain locations. See [this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SsKW7Ysy) for what they return.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class?

Comment: For all the goodness sake, PLEASE get rid of this class.

Comment: Why, exactly? I'm attempting to save myself a bit of time, as I'm going to be calling these operations _a lot_ in my code to come...

Comment: you are saving yourself nothing, at the cost of introducing LOTS of errors and vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hmmm... Explain in greater detail, please..? Also, **note**: I'm not doing this professionally, this is more of an experiment.

Comment: Why don't you use PDO for this? It saves you from SQL injection attacks. If you are trying to build an ORM, try using doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
I am an idiot, apparently, and screwed up a few things.

Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm not doing this professionally, so I don't care about injection attacks at this point in time. All of this is hosted locally and not port forwarded, so none of this data really matters.

Input sanitization is next on my list, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pdo wrapper such as this:

http://pastebin.com/AHdJkCBz

Then in the same directory, add settings.ini.php like this http://pastebin.com/cu1kY8kL

Do not commit this settings file to your repository. Copy and paste it always.

The way to call this would be:

```
function checkPassword($email, $password)
{
    $db = new db();
    $binding = array('emailId'=>$email, 'hashed_password'=>md5($password));
    return $db->single("SELECT id FROM members WHERE pc_address = :emailId AND hashed_password = :hashed_password", $binding);
}
```

Check the whole class for detailed methods.

I have also made two general purpose functions to add/update database.

```
function assetsUtilInsert($table, $params, $debug=false){
    $db = new db();
    if($table && is_array($params)){
        $bindings = $params;
        if(!empty($bindings)) {
            $fields = array_keys($bindings);
            $fieldsvals = array(implode(",",$fields),":" . implode(",:",$fields));
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$fieldsvals[0].") VALUES (".$fieldsvals[1].")";
        }
        if($debug==true)
            echo $sql;
        $result = $db->query($sql,$bindings);
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        assetsUtilInvokeError($this->registry->log, "Could not insert because either table does not exist or parameters is not an array");
    }
}

function assetsUtilUpdate($table, $params, $where, $exit=0){

    $db = new db();
    $sql = '';
    if($table && is_array($params) && is_array($where)){
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
        foreach($params as $key => $val){
            $sql .= $key ."=:$key, ";
        }
        unset($key); unset($val);
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, (strlen($sql)-2));
        $sql .= " WHERE ";
        foreach($where as $key => $val){
            $sql .= $key ."=:$key AND ";
        }
        unset($key); unset($val);
        $bindings = array_merge($params, $where);
        unset($params); unset($where);
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, (strlen($sql)-4));
        if($exit==1){
            echo $sql; exit;
        }
        return $db->query($sql, $bindings);
    } else {
        assetsUtilInvokeError($this->registry->log, "Could not insert because either table does not exist or params is not an array or where condition is not an array");
    }
}
```

I have used log4php for logging. You could adapt with this code.
Just changing the settings.ini.php for driver can help you use the same code for different databases supported by PDO.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have enabled mysqli extension or just test if you can instance outside your class. 
Also can we see how you instance and use your class when you get this error.

**EDIT**

Check mysqli object with var_dump() when you pass to your constructor.

Comment: I've added my index.php (the only place where I call this class) to the question body. As for the MySQLi extension, yes it is enabled as far as I can tell.

Comment: All three return as expected- an instance of the MySQLi class. However, all data appears to be null. Not sure if that's normal or not. Here's a Pastebin of what I get: [link](http://pastebin.com/SsKW7Ysy)